# Embed a Google Map (or Google Earth) inside our web page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here's a gist of what we are trying to do.

We have some co-ordinate information (latitude and longitudes), and a bunch of annotations for these co-ordinates on the server. We want to embed a Google Map (or Google Earth) inside our web page, which shows these co-ordinates as balloons (or some icon) and annotate them with relevant information.

We have seen videos where this is done manually (copying the embed URL into our HTML page, or open a kml/kmz file in Google Earth etc), but we cannot have any manual step in between, as this is used by end users (clients) who cannot do this. We need to do this programmatically.

We want to what is the best way to go about doing this? Also, in the future we want to update the map dynamically with live data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to look at passing the data from the server to the client, either via an AJAX request, or simply by embedding your coordinates etc into the page using PHP or whatever. Look at something like https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 for one example

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

this is the tutorial for the google map..